# IOS/Objective-C: Get Number from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer

I have a JSON dictionary that contains what I will call an integer (in mathematics) i.e. 1.

I would like to save this number to a core data attribute that is an `NSInteger`.  The following code is issuing warning:

> Incompatible Pointer to Integer Conversion initializing NSInteger with an expression of type 'id'

```
 NSInteger insertID = jsonResults[@"insert_id"];
```

I have tried various combinations of `int`, `NSNumber`, etc. to no avail.  Can anyone suggest right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSDictionary` can't store `NSInteger`. It is storing `NSNumber`. So you need to unwrap the `NSNumber`:

```
NSInteger insertID = [jsonResults[@"insert_id"] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

in core data you should save numeric  value as Number Type. 
For eaxample,

**To save:**

insert_id = @(100)//say 100 is your insert_id value

**To read:**

NSInteger insertID = [jsonResults[@"insert_id"] intValue];